# Delphi XE3 Firemonkey autosize/layout problems

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, autosize

Using Firemonkey I have a TVertScrollBox which contains a TPanel which gets dynamically populated with a number of the following TDisplayItem objects.

The problem is that the TDisplayItem’s don’t size properly so the text on the various components is superimposed etc.

I can fix this on the items that are in the visible area of the scrollbox by by getting the sizes of the component parts and making the containers that size etc. I’ve tried refreshing and  application.ProcessMessages to get everything to resize as well as various alignment and warp options but to no avail.

Hopefully I’ve missed a key factor in this and haven’t unearthed a Firemonkey limitation!

Cheers,

Martin.

```
Constructor TDisplayItem.Create(owner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(owner);
  Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
  pnlLabels := TPanel.Create(nil);
  pnlLabels.Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
  pnlLabels.Height := 50;
  pnlLabels.Parent := self;

  lblICAO := TLabel.Create(nil);
  lblICAO.Parent := pnlLabels;
  with lblICAO do
  begin
    text := 'ICAO';
    Height := 30;
    Position.X := 10;
    align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
    TextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter;
    Font.Size := 18;
    FontColor :=  $FF00D000 ;
    Visible := False;
    StyledSettings := [TStyledSetting.ssFamily];//, TStyledSetting.ssFontColor];
  end;

  lblFrom := TLabel.Create(nil);
  lblFrom.Parent := pnlLabels;
  with lblFrom do
  begin
    text := 'From : ';
    Height := 30;
    Position.X := 10;
    Position.y := 2;
    width := 150;
    FontColor :=  $FFFF0000 ;
    StyledSettings := [TStyledSetting.ssFamily];//, TStyledSetting.ssFontColor];
  end;

  lblTo := TLabel.Create(nil);
      lblTo.Parent := pnlLabels;
  with lblTo do
  begin
    text := 'To : ';
    Height := 30;
    Position.X := 170;
    Position.y := 2;
    width := 150;
    FontColor :=  $FFFF0000 ;
    StyledSettings := [TStyledSetting.ssFamily];//, TStyledSetting.ssFontColor];
  end;



 lblStatus := TLabel.Create(nil);
  lblStatus.Parent := pnlLabels;
  with lblStatus do
  begin
    text := 'Status : ';
    Height := 30;
    Position.X := 330;
    Position.y := 2;
    width := 100;
    Font.Size := 10;
    FontColor :=  $FFFF0000 ;
    StyledSettings := [TStyledSetting.ssFamily];//, TStyledSetting.ssFontColor];
  end;

  lblNonGeog  := TLabel.Create(nil);
  with lblNonGeog do
  begin
    text := 'Non-Geog : ';
    Height := 30;
    Position.X := 440;
    Position.y := 2;
    width := 150;
    Font.Size := 10;
    FontColor :=  $FFFF0000 ;
    StyledSettings := [TStyledSetting.ssFamily];//, TStyledSetting.ssFontColor];
  end;
  lblNonGeog.Parent := pnlLabels;

  memItem := TLabel.Create(nil);
  memItem.Parent := self;
  with memItemE do
  begin
    Align := TAlignLayout.alTop;
    DisableFocusEffect := False;
    AutoSize := True;
    WordWrap := True;
  end;
```

Comment: Are you setting the size of your TDisplayItems at any point (either in the component or when creating them)? What is the parent of TDisplayItem?

Comment: The parent is set to be the TPanel that visually contains them. The size is set by iteratively getting the height of each and setting the height of each parent to be the sum of the heights of the child controls.

Comment: Sorry, I meant parent class, not parent control. If the class is TPanel, you can make each label a direct child and avoid the extra panel. Then you control height will be the child with the largest Position.Y+Height. I would advise doing this in the display item class.

Comment: Thanks Mike, it is a TPanel, it's needed as there are multiple child controls and I need to easily handle the layout. The problem seems to be that if it's not in the visible area of the screen, it's not drawn and doesn't have a height other than the default - so when it's scrolled, the displayitems that appear are incorrectly sized/drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally solved it. I was on the right lines thinking it was a drawing issue - when the text of one of the labels was changed a label.dopaint was needed. This then updated the height of the label even if it was not in the display area. The paraent TPanel could then have it's height set correctly by summing the heights of the child components.